# Can foreigners (French) buy land/house in Taiwan to have a foothold?

Tags: legal, taiwan, french-citizens

Me and my brother have been traveling to Taiwan several times now, and we are discussing about buying some flat or land there. So we have our own place to stay and invite some friends.

Some taiwanese told me it might be possible in order to do business. This is not my intent, or only renting while I'm not there.

Would you mind sharing your experience/insights?

**disclaimer:** might be cross-over another stackexchange site, but don't know which one.

Comment: This is more appropriate for [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy residential (not commercial) property if you hold an Alien Registration Card and if Taiwan nationals are able to buy property in your home country.

You are generally not allowed to buy for profit, buy multiple properties etc: only buy a residence for personal use.

You are also "required to apply to the Ministry of Economic Affairs for approval of the intended purchase" with regard to the above criteria

[Source](http://www.expatfocus.com/expatriate-taiwan-buying-property)

And more importantly a Taiwanese [guide](http://www.land.moi.gov.tw/onlinebill/608-n1.pdf) to the relevant Taiwan law, and it's implementation, along with the actual act it refers to [The Land Act](https://www.land.moi.gov.tw/onlinebill/505-n.doc)